# Magento Indexes "update on save" not working

Tags: magento, indexing

I’m experiencing a problem with indexes, some of them are not auto updating after I save a product, though on Index Management, all indexes are set to "Update on save”. This causes internal links to break. We have installed an extension called "Group Deals”, as our site is a daily-deal site, so all products pages look like coupons. What happens is, if I add a new product or I edit an existing one, most of the links to products, on any category, start redirecting to the default magento product page, instead of the "daily-deal" product page. But, If I go to Index Management and reindex everything, then links start working good, correctly redirecting to the "daily-deal" product page. How can I fix this?

Thank you, 
Alex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's impossible to say, and too complicated a question to answer directly.  However, the most common reason for this is an unexpected error during the "index on save" codepath.  It's also possible you have extensions installed that are incorrectly, leading to an "un-indexed" state that Magento's not aware of.

I'd check your error logs for any exceptions/errors related to the information you're after.

Comment: How can you find errors on codepath? On error.log isn't appear nothing...